# Mass replace of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace all the child elements in a certain element to DIVs.

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I've tried `replaceElements($('#wrapper'))`:

```
function replaceElements($element){
    var children = $element.find("*");
    var current;
    for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
        current = $(children[i]);
        current.replaceWith("<div>" + current.html() + "</div>");
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work because when it tries to change the N+1 element it all ready doesn't exist because it was replaced when doing the Nth element. N+1 is a descendant of N and thus is being changed when changing the `.html()` of N. Preserving element attributes is not an issue here.

How can I change all the child SPANs into DIVs, please?

Comment: Are all elements really that simple? (No attributes, just standard tags)?

Comment: why not get the whole wrapper content and replace each span elements and then use $('#wrapper').html(newContent)?

Comment: Question was locked before I clicked the "Post" button, but it's very simple to do IF that is really all you need: `var w = document.getElementById('wrapper');w.innerHTML = w.innerHTML.replace(/<\/?span/g, function (m){return m.replace('span', 'div')});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the html content in the replaced element, instead need to add the dom elements to it

```js
function replaceElements($element) {

  $element.find("*").replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<div></div>', {
      html: this.childNodes
    });
  })
}

replaceElements($('#wrapper'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <span>1
    <span>2
      <span>3
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Note: No attributes of the elements will be copied